# Solving for mod indirectly

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

How many positive integers $n$ exist such that $\frac{680}{n}$ is an integer?

So, this is quite obvious,

$680 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$

How should I solve for $n$? There will be multiple $n$?

Answer (score 1):

$$680=10\cdot68=2^3\cdot17\cdot5$$

So, the number of positive [divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)s $=(3+1)(1+1)(1+1)$

Answer (score 0):

There as many solutions as divisors of $680$. Decompose $680$ into its prime factors:
$$680=2^3\cdot 5^1 \cdot 17^1.$$
Hence there are $4\cdot2\cdot 2=16$  solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By the FTA (Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic - existence and uniqueness of prime factorizations), if $\,p,q,r\,$ are primes then the positive divisors of $\, p^i q^j r^k $ are *precisely* the naturals of the form $\,p^{\bar i}q^{\bar j} q^{\bar k}\,$ where $\,\bar i< i,\ \bar j< j,\  \bar k < k.\ $ Thus the set of divisors is in bijection with the set of sequences of naturals $(i,j,k)$ satisfying said inequalities. Such sequences are easy to count.

**Remark** $\ $ The is a protoypical example of how FTA reduces many divisibility problems on integers to *simpler* problems on (exponent) vectors.